# Check Firebase whether offline data present locally or not.(Uploaded or Not)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and having an issue that I am not able to check wether my offline data has uploaded to firebase server or not. Is there any way to check this with and without internet connection? 
Because Firebase reference.setinfo firstly saves the data locally and then on the server.

Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled will do it for us, but in some conditions when the data saved locally is in a large amount then the risk to loose users data will increase.

We want to logout the user and also want to make sure that all of its data will be saved on the firebase server.

Comment: Quick answer below. I highly recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as that is the best way to increase the chances we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Any Firebase Database writes are locally persisted if the call completes. If they ever fail, it raises an exception.

To know if the write was persisted to the server, use a completion block as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#add_a_completion_block.